# Moto G 2 (2014) Not Charging!

Tags: battery, charging

My phone is a Moto G (2014) XT1068. It has recently stopped charging for some reason. This morning it was charging and tonight, it decided that it would be a prick and not charge. Anyhow I tried cleaning the connector, using various cables/plugs, wiping the cache partition, booting it up in recovery mode and nothing has worked. Could someone give me any more suggestions. I can't go to the phone repair shop at the moment and my warranty has expired :( as I am in boarding school and cannot leave for another 2 and a half weeks.
Does anyone know any suggestions on what to do??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if you changed the charger as well. Try doing that. If you don't have a charger, try charging from USB port of a lap top. If that works, then it looks like your charger is culprit. If this suggestion works, will convert into answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I put a micro usb port into my laptop. The phone doesn't charge but there is a constant notification on my mac saying "unplug usb device using too much power"

Comment: Am guessing it to be a hardware issue...Sorry can't be of help

Answer (score 1):

I have found myself in the position that *all* my micro-usb cables had gotten worn out, and even after having tested several, I had to buy a new cable to charge my device.  Those connectors just aren't that robust.  Can you find anyone who has a shiny new USB cable that you could try for a minute, just to see if that solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try other battery and charge. Also check 3 point connector of battery on PCB.